# Apply conditional formatting to specific substring matches from REGEX

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets, how can you apply conditional formatting to specific substring matches from regex, rather than the entire row?

If the input is roughly:

Column B

Row 4: hello [t- my name] is ___. So happy to [t- meet you].

Row 5: this is a test.

Row 6: [t- Can you] [c- help] with [t- that]?

---

Expected output would be:

Column B

Row 4: hello **[t- my name]** is ___. So happy to **[t- meet you]**.

Row 5: this is a test.

Row 6: **[t- Can you]** [c- help] with **[t- that]**?

---

The custom conditional formatting I've applied to range `B4:B` is:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B4, "\[t- (.*)\]")
```

But this bolds the entire cell's text where the regex match is true.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Sheets CF does not offer this possibility. You might try a script.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to do it in conditional formatting rather than do it manually, cell by cell and bold out specific parts of a cell's content